# Standard test documents for new packages

Tags: package-writing

I'm putting together a package that offers general functionality that I think would be helpful for lots of LaTeX users and in lots of documents.

I've rolled my own test cases, but I can't help but think I might be reinventing the wheel. So, are there any generic test cases with associated packages, e.g. a simple article, report, book, or KOMA-script examples that I should be running it against to demonstrate functionality and interaction with other packages?

Comment: I would say: test what you can, store your package on CTAN, and wait for bug reports!

Comment: @CarLaTex - that's quite literally asking for trouble... Probably not a bad idea. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Done, but wait before accepting, maybe someone else will add a more sensible answer.

Comment: @AndyClifton I'd say it depends a lot on what your package does. For instance, one of my current projects is a package to format numerical output. My test cases include all kinds of numbers I can think of (there are _lots_ of tests :-) and interaction with other number-related packages, like `fp`, `pgfmath`, and `siunitx`. It wouldn't make sense to test the interaction with KOMA because it's completely unrelated. On the other hand a package that deals with text layout is on the complete other side of the spectrum... Now that we're at it, what is your package about? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a package writer or maintainer, hence I do not have experience in package testing, but perhaps posting this answer will attract a more sensible one.

If I were you, I would do all the possible tests which come to my mind, then I would post my package on CTAN and wait for bug reports.

If there are <s>bugs</s> undocumented features, I'm sure someone will soon find them.